# How to gradually slide out view when list or scroll view is scrolled like bottom options in current facebook app

Tags: android

How to achieve this effect. So if I scroll down, menu bar is slide out and when i scroll up menu bar i slides back in. How is this effect called anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code in here to achieve it.

https://gist.github.com/JohNan/df776dc4926a1676cc05

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout this website ( https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32#App ), starting from heading -

"App Bar" Dependency -

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Xml from the site-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior=
        "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

"enterAlways" is the keyword for layout appearing after scrolling up again.